# Display the names of specific elements in a plot

Tags: r, visualization

I have a volcano plot as shown in

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UreCs.jpg

I need to display the names of ONLY the elements which are shown in red color out of 19000 elements

How can I do that?

Also is there anyways I could represent those elements in the red color in different sizes based on their fold change and p-values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can label elements with the `text` function. You could change the size of elements with the `cex` argument to `plot`, for instance

```
plot(1:10, cex=1:10*0.2)
text(c(1,2)+0.4, c(1,2), c("P1", "P2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Jana,

You can annotate your plots with `text`. You can change many of the different elements of your plot by passing additional parameters in your call to `plot`. Most of these parameters are discussed in detail on the `?par` page. Finally, you can specify logic in your calls to plot based on something of interest. Here's a quick example:

```
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))

with(df, plot(x,y
    , cex = ifelse(abs(x) > 2, .75, 1.5)     #Size
    , col = ifelse(abs(x) > 2 | abs(y) > 2, "red", "blue")     #Color
    , pch = ifelse(abs(x) > 2 | abs(y) > 2, 4, 6)     #Type of point
    )
    )
text(2, -3, "This is text on my plot")
```